# web.py always converts variables to strings

Tags: python, web.py

I'm using web.py to create a site, and to pass config values and common functions between the backend and frontend templates I am using a custom class object. I am using a base template, and could not figure out how to pass a variable to a base template so I just pass it to the child template and then do

```
$var o: $:obj
```

but when accessing it in the base template, I get

```
<object.object instance at 0x12345678>
```

and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've added ':' before all references to the variable, but it does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done like this:

```
$var o = obj
```

Comment: Hmmm. Strange. I tried that before, but that didn't work. I guess it was because I named them the same thing, and they happen to be in the same scope. Thanks, that works now!